# Use embedded string as variable name

Tags: ruby

I have a YAML file that uses the encoding `__firstname__` as a placeholder which signifies that an existing method `firstname` should be used, rather than the literal string in a subsequent process.

I am trying to understand the most ruby way to to do this.  Basically, I need to extract the part between the underscores and send it to an object.  Here is pseudocode:

```
variable = '__firstname__'
if variable is prefixed and suffixed with underscores
   result = object.send(variable.removeunderscores)
else
   result = variable
end

puts result
```

I was about to write this procedurally like this, but this is the type of thing that I think ruby can less clunkily if only I knew the language better.

What is a clean why to write this?

Comment: Maybe something like: `result = variable.gsub!(/\A_|_\Z/, '')) ? object.send(variable) : variable`? It's destructive and honestly not that elegant, but it is a one-liner if that's your kind of thing. Personally, I think your approach is plenty clean for what you're trying to do.

Comment: And actually, that one-liner isn't entirely correct. Sometimes having longer code is nice just to make sure you're doing things properly. Performance-wise, your current solution and that one-liner are pretty similar anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with verbose code if it's clear to read IMO.

I'd do something like this using [String#start_with?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F) and [String#end_with?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-end_with-3F):

```
variable = '__firstname__'
if variable.start_with?("__") && variable.end_with?("__")
   result = object.send(variable[2...-2])
else
   result = variable
end
```